# QKeySequence using mouse scroll

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qkeysequence

I'm trying to create a QAction that will trigger when user uses Shift + mouse scroll up/down.
Is there a way to create a [QKeySequence](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qkeysequence.html) corresponding to this, to set the QAction shortcut ?
If not, what could I do, besides overriding my widget's wheelEvent? I wish I had a cleaner solution than this.